# Overriding default colours in a ggplot diagram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm fairly new to R and am trying to change the colours of my generated diagram.
[image]

```
 p = ggplot(plasma1, aes(x=Day, y=Control, colour=Supp))
 + theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill='white', colour='black'))
 + geom_point(size=2, shape=21) 
 + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Control-SEMcontrol, ymax=Control+SEMcontrol), width=1)

 p + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank()) 
 + xlab("X") + ylab("Y") + geom_line(linetype="dashed")
```

I've looked at themes() but I can only seem to change the grid lines and not the trend line. (Ideally I would like to change red & blue to red & black

Comment: Look into scale_colour_manual.

Comment: how about using `colour` argument in `geom_line`

Comment: Try adding `+scale_color_manual(values=c(C="red",N="black"))` to the ggplot definition.

Comment: geom_line doesn't need a colour, @pcantalupo, it inherits aes from the main call to ggplot.

Comment: as @jlhoward mentioned, `scale_colour_manual()` but also `scale_colour_brewer()` for more readable colors if you're not tied to red, blue, and black. See the [documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/)

Comment: there's also the `ggthemes` package with other color scales (like tableau)

Comment: @jlhoward Thank you! That has worked. Could you write it as an answer please, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note: The convention on SO is that "answers" are reserved for reproducible code that demonstrates a solution. Anything less (like a suggestion) belongs in a comment. This is why it is so essential that questioners *provide their data* as part of the question; otherwise we have to make some up for you, which most people are (justifiably) unwilling to do.

The answer you asked for is below, but before getting into that you should be aware that `ggplot`'s default color scheme is carefully chosen, so you should only change it if there is a good reason. The problem is that human evolution has caused certain colors (like red) to get a perceptual boost relative to other colors. So if you have a red curve and a black curve, the red curve leaves a stronger "impression". This fact is used extensively in certain fields (like advertising) to psychologically manipulate the viewer, but it has no place in scientific data visualization. The `ggplot` defaults, which are based on the HCL color system (which in turn is based on the [Munsell color system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Munsell_color_system)), try to achieve two objectives: to create a color palette where each color is maximally distinguishable from all the other colors, and to even out the relative perceptual impact. There is a fairly technical discussion of this topic [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.88.7838&rep=rep1&type=pdf), and some nice examples [here](http://hclwizard.org/why-hcl/).

Bottom line: don't change the colors unless you have a really good reason to do so.

Having said all that, the simple answer to your question is to use `scale_color_manual(...)`, as below:

```
# all this to set up the example - you have this already
set.seed(1)    # for reproducible example
x <- rep(c(1,2,4,8,11,14), each=5)
df1 <- data.frame(Day=x,Control=125*(1-exp(-x/5))+rnorm(30,sd=25),Supp="N")
df2 <- data.frame(Day=x,Control=90*(1-exp(-x/3))+rnorm(30,sd=25),Supp="C")
plasma1 <- aggregate(Control~Day+Supp,rbind(df2, df1), FUN=function(x)c(Control=mean(x),SEMcontrol=sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))))
plasma1 <- data.frame(plasma1[,1:2],plasma1[[3]])

# you start here
library(ggplot2)
ggp <- ggplot(plasma1, aes(x=Day, y=Control, color=Supp))+
  geom_point(size=3, shape=21)+
  geom_line(linetype="dashed")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Control+SEMcontrol, ymin=Control-SEMcontrol), width=0.3)+
  theme_bw()+theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
ggp + scale_color_manual(values=c(C="red",N="black"))
```

Which produces this:

[image]

As mentioned in one of the comments, you could also use one of the [Brewer Palettes](http://colorbrewer2.org/) developed by Prof. Cynthia Brewer at Penn State. These were originally intended for cartographic applications, but have become widely used generally in scientific visualization.

```
ggp + scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the interesting comments.